# How to unite views in GridView in the center?

Tags: android, gridview

I am using GridView to create color picker. There is a circle inside each cell. Even if I set wrap content for layout_width and layout_height there is always gap between columns. I want to unite cells in the center or remove these gaps.

Here is my GridView's layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/color_picker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="3" />
```

CircleView class

```
public class CircleView extends View {
    private static final String TAG = "CircleView";
    private Paint mCirclePaint;
    private int mCircleColor;

    private Paint mStrokePaint;
    private int mStrokeColor;

    private int mWidthInDp;
    private int mHeightInDp;

    public CircleView(Context context){
        super(context);

        mCirclePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(mCircleColor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasuredSpec, int heightMeasuredSpec) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMeasure: ");

        setMeasuredDimension(mWidthInDp, mHeightInDp);
    }

    public void setLayoutParamsInDp(int width, int height){
        this.mWidthInDp = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, width, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        this.mHeightInDp = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, height, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    public void setCircleColor(int color){
        this.mCircleColor = color;
        mCirclePaint.setColor(mCircleColor);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int centerX = mWidthInDp / 2;
        int centerY = mHeightInDp / 2;

        float radius = Math.min(mWidthInDp, mWidthInDp) / 2;

        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, mCirclePaint);
        canvas.save();
    }
}
```

GridView adapter

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        CircleView circleView = new CircleView(mContext);
        circleView.setCircleColor(mColors.get(position));
        circleView.setLayoutParamsInDp(50, 50);
        return circleView;
    }
```

Here is the output. How can I delete gaps between circles?

[image]

Comment: can you post xml of item view for gridview?

Comment: @kam1234 I am not using item view for grid view, I have created a circle view and put it into gridview in adapter class. I posted circle view and adapter classes.

Comment: can you post  your adapter class

Comment: try to use below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in GridView as parent. Add another layout as parent and in there add GridView with width & height as wrap content!

Comment: I added parent layout and added padding to the start and end. Now it is working. But I am wondering is there any way to do this automatically.

Comment: When you use GridView as parent it has to take all the space available whether you use match parent or wrap content. In case, it is a child, the wrap content actually works and no extra space is used. However, not tested but I think fixed width and height can also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/color_picker"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dip"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dip">
</GridView>
```

Comment: try to add this to gridview android:adjustViewBounds="true"

Comment: I added android:adjustViewBounds="true" but nothing changed.

Comment: I could achieve this problem by adding parent layout and adding padding to start and end.